# php quiz how to query 10 rows based on levels

Tags: php

I have a table(quiz). And the fields are id,question,answer, and level.
There Many questions for level 1, many questions for level 2 and so on. Please how do i query 10 rows based on the levels consecutively i.e

question1(level 1)
question2(level 2)
question3(level 3)
..to
question10(level 10)

this is what i have so far:

```
$con->prepare("SELECT*FROM quiz WHERE level IN (1,2,3,4,5.....10) limit 0,10");
```

but the result i get is only 10 questions on level 1. Please i also want it to be random

Comment: Thanks kenny..let me give it try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt, though perhaps it needs a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM quiz
WHERE level BETWEEN 1 AND 10
GROUP BY level
ORDER BY RAND(), level
```

Second attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM quiz
  WHERE level BETWEEN 1 AND 10
  ORDER BY RAND()
) tmp
GROUP BY level
ORDER BY level
```

Comment: Yea..it work great..thanks so much..

Comment: @kenny.. I noticed that the query is only randoming the first instance of the question per level...    I.e id:1 question1(level1)    id:50 question2(level) and so. I.e the id are constant but only changes position.    When the page refreshes, it only changes id:50 as quest 1 as in rand..but i want it that when page refreshes, it can generate id:2 question1(level1)    id:29 question2(level2) and so on

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought might happen. I added a second attempt.

Comment: Now all is well...thanks kenny..